# Assigning colors and value to a cell, without having to hit the run button, based on a number input into a cell

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

Is there a way to autofill cells, without having to hit the run button, based on a number input into a cell?

For example, if I input a 1 into any cell, that cell and the cell one space up and one space left will turn blue with the number 1 inside?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a fairly simple thing to do. There is an event in Excel for changes that happen on a worksheet called "Worksheet.Change." This function is passed the address of the cell that is changed on the worksheet. Since you will have the row and column of the changed cell, you can move left/right and up/down from there and change the cells as you desire. A quick google search for "MS Excel worksheet onchange event" will get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on rbigjoepro75's answer.  Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim v As Variant
    
    If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    v = Target.Value
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(-1, -1).Value = v
        Target.Offset(-1, -1).Interior.Color = vbBlue
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

If we put a *9* in cell **F8** we get:

[image]

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**